# ENV not setting in Dockerized cron job that calls script but does set in Dockerfile that calls script directly

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile

**Why is the ENV set correctly in the container by the first Dockerfile but not by the second one?**

I have a small script that I want to run every 10 minutes. I dockerized cron and have it call the script (I know that might be a little weird). If I hardcode the env into the script everything works as intended. But I need to pass them in the Dockerfile instead.

This Dockerfile dockerizes the lone script and the ENV is set appropriately.

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENV c_setting=5

CMD ["python", "script.py"]
```

Right now the script just calls `os.environ[c_setting]` and prints it. Like I said, this finds the ENV set in the dockerfile correctly.

This is the cron version of the dockerfile. All it does is call the same script every 10 minutes.

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim

WORKDIR /app

COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY . /app

ENV c_setting=5

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

The cron aspect of this works just fine. It hits the `KeyError(c_setting)` exception at the right time intervals lol.

**Why is the ENV set in the first Dockerfile but not in the second?**

Something to do with layers and ordering?

script.py for ref

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    print(os.environ["c_setting"])
```

crontab for ref

```
* * * * * cd ../app && /usr/local/bin/python script.py >> script.log 2>>error.log
```

Comment: As far as I know cron doesn’t take environment variables for the commands from the environment it’s started from. You’ll need to put the variable definition into crontab for it to take effect when cron runs the command.

Comment: I've linked this to two very similar questions.  The "Docker set environment variables" question addresses the very specific case of making Dockerfile `ENV` or `docker run -e` options accessible to cron jobs, but the "where can I set" question discusses some much simpler approaches directly using the crontab.